# Dynamics AX 2012 - AIF Access Using C# Walkthrough

Tags: c#, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I'm probably missing something simple, but I'm tired of fighting with it.  There seem to be quite a few examples for connecting to the stock AIF services, but I have yet to find a concise, working example for connecting to a custom service.

Assuming the following:

```
Service reference configured in the project with a namespace of MyService

That service has two methods exposed from Dynamics AX that we'll call:   
     helloWorld()    and   helloWorld2(str yourName)

Each method returns a simple string
```

What C# code would you use to call each method and write the result to a label?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using [MyProjectName].MyService;
```

...

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
CallContext context = new CallContext();
label1.Text = client.helloWorld(context);

MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
CallContext context = new CallContext();
label1.Text = client.helloWorld2(context, "test");
```

...